# Этимология слова "банальность"

Tags: этимология

Прочитала вопрос про "капитана Очевидность" и подумала: а какое происхождение слова "банальный"? Оно, вообще, русское?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Банальный" - от французского "banal".  Значения, которые выдает "переводчик": банальный, тривиальный, обывательский, повседневный, безвкусный, заигранный, избитый, пошлый, усталый.

Если копать глубже, то по Фасмеру БАНАЛЬНЫЙ - из франц. banal, заимствованного из франк. ban "изгнание, отлучение", "то, что характеризует полную меру объявления вне закона, отлучения в рамках данного судебного округа".

Значение уже несколько иное

Answer (score 0):

27.09.2013

```
 ЛИЧНОЕ ПИСЬМО

                            “Здравствуйте, Михаил!

 Ваши извинения принимаются.

 Из всех тех, с кем мне довелось (с ОГРОМНЫМ интересом!) пообщаться на этом брызжущем ядом (на посетителей) сайте, Вы – ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ воспитанный и культурный человек, уверяю Вас!

 Спасибо Вам и за другую информацию, о чём я Вам сегодня же напишу в Вашу личную е-почту!

                                 С уважением – 
                                                          Борис Александров
```

P.S. Я почему-то думаю, что мы с Вами со временем подружимся и даже, вполне вероятно, начнём периодически навещать друг друга. Я лично был бы не против. Не было ещё в моём ближнем окружении ни одного Михаила, с которым бы у меня НЕ было приятельских (а с некоторыми даже – истинно дружеских!) отношений.”

```
                       КОНЕЦ ПИСЬМА К МИХАИЛУ

 Для остальных же посетителей сайта этот вопрос исчерпан, я полагаю. (Ну, кроме хакеров, понятно, о которых я уже всё понял, потому что они уже сами признались мне в лице бегемотуса, у которого язык, похоже, без костей.)

 Да! Чуть не забыл. Поскольку ноги моей виртуальной здесь больше НЕ будет отныне, оставлю здесь на добрую память свой дилетантский рассказ об одном забавном, но крайне поучительном, на мой взгляд, случае, произошедшем не так давно в японской Прибалтике. Только не с коровой и быком, а сами сейчас узнаете, с кем.

 (Приведу свой рассказ в том же самом виде, в котором я вчера рассказал его милостивым модераторам этого сайта.)

 “Однажды один молодой и чересчур самоуверенный студент перебрал с дружками саке и, естественно, проспал утрецо. А этим злосчастным (как вскоре выяснилось) для него утрецом должен был начаться выпускной экзамен для его курса.

 Благо, что его мамаша в последний (для него) момент на всякий японский случай заглянула в его свинарник. То есть я хотел сказать: “хэю” (его комнату). Ну, видно что-то ей почудилось, этой японской маме, или она была немного в курсе, что у её раздолбая-сынули важное для его будущей жизненной карьеры событие должно состояться. Как раз об этом наша правдивая история умалчивает.

 Тут важно другое. В последнюю секунду, даже не продрав, как следует по самурайской традиции, свой второй глаз (и не заглянув даже, мильпардон, в туалет!) этот японский бедолага впрыгивает в одном носке в свою навороченную японскую куруму. (Остальную свою одежонку он – слава Синте! – на себя успел-таки кое-как нагрузть на бегу. Хоть и на левую сторону (что было крайне с его стороны неосмотрительно!!!) Ладно, нашёл скважину замочка зажигания. И даже почти сразу умудрился запихнуть туда вместо ногтя правильный ключ.
 А по дороге его-то и подкараулили два его старых, хоть и невидимых, друга – Воспитатель и Трезвенник. Вставших пораньше и заранее забежавших вперёд. (Потому что, как говорят в Японии: “Хаяоки-ва саммон-но току”. Ну, то есть: “Кто рано вcтаёт, тот получает три медные монетки”.) И эти его настоящие друзья насовали ему перед самый капот длиннющую вереницу из других таких же своих трудновоспитуемых. Тоже друзей.
 И понятно, что когда в очередной раз, перед очередным японским фонариком, ближайшая к его переднему бамперу курума (НЕ навороченная) в очередной раз прозевала момент зажигания зелёненького и несколько подзадержалась на промежуточном финише, то этот страдалец на следующем же светофорчике пробкой вылетел из своей четырёхколёсной арматуры и сверхбодро наговорил старенькому “предстоящему” водителю даже больше того, что хотел вначале. (Потому что в момент, когда совсем уж было собрался остановиться, красочно описав внешний облик старичка, на свою беду увидел молодую японскую тоже мамашу, ведущую в школу своего будущего копию нашего героя. (Героя этого рассказа, я имею в виду.)
 Тогда студента окончательно повело, и он выложил незадаче-водителю всё про родственников того. Вплоть до самого часа “Ч” перед решительным вторжением самурайской армии на Айнские острова.
 Это-то его и сгубило окончательно (ну, ТО, что он “дал свечку” (как говорят между собой психиатры) и вдарился в исторические и демографические изыски): резко загорелся зелёный, изумлённый, но так и оставшийся по-самурайски спокойным старичок (поклонник, кстати, теории “От Судьбы НЕ Уйти, Хоть Ты Тресни!”) благополучно дал газу и быстро скрылся за первым же поворотом, увозя в натренированной памяти последнюю фразу дорожного филолога о том, что его (старичка) мать была и́ну и пасла скотину. А вздыбившийся посреди дорожной разметки незадача-студент был не только, в свою очередь, обласкан водителями, жавшимися по западную, советскую (тогда) сторону задка его железного буцефалоса, но и получил добрую плюху по бамперу от ближайшего заднего соседа, умолявшего всё это время светофор и не включившегося поэтому в монолог к старичку. Пришлось нашему страдальцу окончательно подзадержаться до подъезда дорожной полиции (сквозь-то всю эту пробку!).
 Долго ли, коротко ли, но к КОНЦУ госа окончательно взвинченный бедняга таки успел. (Помог его истинный друг Воспитатель.) 
 Исполненный недостойной истинного самурая ярости и псевдобусидошных планов достать вечером из-под кучи грязного белья (сваленного в углу его хэи) свою давно не точенную и изрядно подзаржавевшую катану и во что бы то ни стало разыскать уже вечером вредоносного тормоза-старикашку.
 И какую же картину он созерцает перед собой, враз, как по волшебству, остывая?
 Прямо перед ним, за экзаменационным столом, в гордом одиночестве и с истинно самурайским спокойствием сидит и приветливо улыбается ему давешний старичок из скромной, но зато истинно самурайской курумы. Ну тот самый, который узнал, что его покойная матушка была в молодости на самом деле обычной собакой и – ещё до его рождения – привольно бегала по обильно осакуренным японским просторам, помогая добрым японским пастухам. А в глазах старичка не светится ничего, кроме вселенской самурайской доброты.”

                      В любой момент к вашим услугам –

                                                           Борис Александров

А! P.S. Раз такое дело резко выявилось с е-адресами-невидимками, недоступными для простого расейского народа, влепляю сюда адрес своего е-почтового ящика, будь ласка! Вот он: "konev.bor@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Изыди, дилетант!

Comment: >надеюсь не очень огорчить "Надюшку", написав, что слово “бáналь”,   
  
Надею не очень Вас огорчить, сказав, что Вы можете гулять лесом.

Comment: Это отнюдь не дилетант, а очень грамотный спамер. Если бы он вопросы писал, можно было бы метку "спам" прицепить. А так - ну ни к чему не прицепишься...

Comment: Не верь, не бойся, не проси. (С)
 Не верь доброжелателям.
 Не бойся бана. 
 Не проси понимания. 

На Все личные наезды отвечаю ссылкой на эту запись.
 Для привата: behemothus@mail.ru

Comment: Как это там было в самом начале... "Курсы американского английского"? @Boris-Al, так это были вы!..

Comment: Какие ещё, пáрдон ми, курсы американского английского??? И в каком таком "самом начале"? Самом начале ЧЕГО?? Бытия? В начале было Слово, конечно, но при чём тут я? Загадка!.. Хоть ешьте меня с маслом – не въезжаю. 

Мы тут, в основном, - дилетанты, как нас уже чуть выше отрекомендовала главный специалист по гэльскому языку, древней истории и, наверное, даже Фасмеру Ирина Григорьева (возможно даже - моя родственница, если у неё есть кто-то в Питере). Кроме того, непонятно также: мы тут происхождение слов выясняем или переходим на личности?

Comment: >мы тут происхождение слов выясняем или переходим на личности?  
  
Что Вы тут делаете, сказать трудно. Скорее всего Саморекоамой занимаетесь.
Во всяком случае ни о каком выяснении "происхождении слов" в Ващеи исполнении речи в Вашем исполнении не идет. 
Для этого надо иметь хотя бы элементарные знания по предмету. Вы не дилетант - Вы шарлатан. Ничего личного, это факт.

И с каких это пор у троллей завелись родственники?

Comment: @Boris-Al, неужели вы такой молодой, что не помните этой истории? В России широкие массы познакомились с понятием "спам" через рассылку рекламы московских "курсов американского английского".

Вы в каждое своё сообщение в конце вставляете подводку: "... а самые интересные сведения по этому вопросу вы найдёте на моём сайте, и вот кстати его адрес". Как хотите, но это _очень похоже_ на спам. Очень!

Comment: Ха. Ха. Ха.

Кстати, корифей Вы наш дорогой, а что такое "Саморекоамой".

Comment: @Михаил stopkran!

Признавайтесь лучше: это у Вас – что? – для всех новичков тут, на сайте, шуточки такие заготовлены, чтобы выяснить КТО я, ОТКУДА, сколько мне лет и чем занимаюсь по жизни? Вообще-то ТАК людей спрашивают только питерские уголовники. Из культурной столицы нашей дорогой. Ну и благовещенские, конечно. Из моего родного города Благовещенска, стало быть. (Который – город Благ – Господь недавно за что-то затопил с помощью Амура и Зеи. Послал Благо, так сказать. Либо за подобные вопросы, либо, что скорее всего, – за перевыполнение плана по толерантности.) Как спрашивают в других

Comment: в других городах – не знаю, не случалось ещё, чтобы кто-то наезжал. Почему-то.
Кстати, о Благовещенске: чего же спрашиваете, коли Вам уже за меня бегемотус всё разболтал?! Я – шарлатан и тролль без родственников. И хитрый спамер-графоман. А ещё (согласно досье Доцента-L Ирины Григорьевой на меня) я – дилетант плюс главный спец по клюкве плюс толстый минус: похож на беса, страшно пугающего нашу Доцента-L Ирину.
ДА! И с мозгами у меня, как она уже доложила всем, не в порядке. Представляете: даже не знаю количества людей на Земле до третьего знака после запятой, а что ещё кошмарнее – не ведаю,

Comment: не ведаю, дурень такой: сколько людей отправилось на Тот Свет за последние пятьсот лет!
Общий привет семье!

Да, мой Адмирал, чуть не забыл! Если будете продолжать ставить мне “собаку”, я буду ставить такую же и Вам.

Б.А.

Comment: Как его пропоносило-то...
А про собаку - сильно. 
Вы, конечно, достойны этого эпитета, но он здесь используется во вполне мирных целях.

Comment: ни-чё-не-понял. Мой единственный вопрос - о вашей молодости - носил, скорее, риторический характер (я сомневаюсь, что вы не знакомы с интернетом конца 90-х). Я не спрашивал, откуда вы и чем занимаетесь. 

Про "собаку" - проявите немного внимания и посмотрите чужие вопросы, собака используется для создания ссылки на профиль участника.

Если вы всё-таки никогда не получали по почте незаказанных писем, говорю вам прямо: спам - это навязчивая реклама.

Comment: Уважаемый Борис Александров! Позвольте дать Вам совет. Не принимайте близко к сердцу то, что пишут на форумах. Если Вы собираетесь и дальше общаться в интернете, постарайтесь абстрагироваться от своего Я - для этого и нужен ник. Представьте, что общаются здесь не люди, а их "аватары" (Вы видели такой фильм?).

Кстати, в профиле Вашем действительно не видно вашего адреса.

Answer (score 0):

(Временный ответ [[@Boris-Al](/users/2087/boris-al)](/users/2087/boris-al) не по теме, просьба не удалять, пока Boris-Al не прочитает) - офф-топик

Уважаемый [[@Boris-Al](/users/2087/boris-al)](/users/2087/boris-al)!

Злые хакеры выломали кнопку комментариев также и для меня. И я так же не вижу в вашем профиле электронного адреса, как и вы в моём. Это всё - особенности движка данного форума, тут нет ничего ни к кому личного.

Мой адрес: exdestinato@list.ru

Впрочем, я не думаю, что он нам понадобится. Раз вы новичок, ваш спам был неосознанным, и я был виноват, назвав вас опытным и хитрым спамером.

Я не знаю, дилетант вы или нет, но вы *пишете, как дилетант*. Чтобы вызвать у сообщества хоть чуть-чуть доверия, нужны так называемые пруфы или пруфлинки (почитайте, например, правила Википедии) - ссылки на авторитетные источники. При этом, вы, конечно, не можете ссылаться на свой сайт, как на авторитетный источник (так как его авторитетность надо пока ещё доказывать).